# Concept for recipe-based parsing of webpages needed

Tags: ruby, parsing, rules

I'm working on a web-scraping solution that grabs totally different webpages and lets the user define rules/scripts in order to extract information from the page.
I started scraping from a single domain and build a parser based on Nokogiri.
Basically everything works fine.
I could now add a ruby class each time somebody wants to add a webpage with a different layout/style.
Instead I thought about using an approach where the user specifies elements where content is stored using xpath and storing this as a sort of recipe for this webpage.

Example: The user wants to scrape a table-structure extracting the rows using a hash (column-name => cell-content)

I was thinking about writing a ruby function for extraction of this generic table information once:

```
# extracts a table's rows as an array of hashes (column_name => cell content)
# html - the html-file as a string
# xpath_table - specifies the html table as xpath which hold the data to be extracted

def basic_table(html, xpath_table)
  xpath_headers = "#{xpath_table}/thead/tr/th"
  html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)   

  html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
  row_headers = html_doc.xpath(xpath_headers)
  row_headers = row_headers.map do |column|
    column.inner_text
  end

  row_contents = Array.new

  table_rows  = html_doc.xpath('#{xpath_table}/tbody/tr')
  table_rows.each do |table_row|    

    cells = table_row.xpath('td')
    cells = cells.map do |cell|
        cell.inner_text
    end

    row_content_hash = Hash.new
    cells.each_with_index do |cell_string, column_index|
        row_content_hash[row_headers[column_index]] = cell_string
    end

    row_contents << [row_content_hash]
  end
  return row_contents
end
```

The user could now specify a website-recipe-file like this:

```
<basic_table xpath='//div[@id="grid"]/table[@id="displayGrid"]'
```

The function basic_table is referenced here, so that by parsing the website-recipe-file I would know that I can use the function basic_table to extract the content from the table referenced by the xPath.
This way the user can specify simple recipe-scripts and only has to dive into writing actual code if he needs a new way of extracting information.
The code would not change every time a new webpage needs to be parsed.
Whenever the structure of a webpage changes only the recipe-script would need to be changed.

I was thinking that someone might be able to tell me how he would approach this. Rules/rule engines pop into my mind, but I'm not sure if that really is the solution to my problem. 
Somehow I have the feeling that I don't want to "invent" my own solution to handle this problem.
Does anybody have a suggestion?

J.